# UIScrollView scroll to previous UITextView when selecting another UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have a screen with multiple fields. Some are UITextView, some are UITextField.

The issue is whenever I'm editing a field, say field 1, and the scroll to another field, say field 10, in the bottom of the page and select it, the scrollView scrolls automatically back to field 1. The first responder is in field 10 and when I try to type it scrolls back to it.

Why is this and how can I prevent the scrollView to scroll to previous field?

Edit:

Here is more context to my ViewController.

I Implemented some delegate function

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // do something with titlelabel text
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // call some closure, store value of textField.text into a variable
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // call some closure, store value of textField.text into a variable
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // call some closure, store value of textView.text into a variable
    }
    
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // call some closure, store value of textView.text into a variable
    }
```

I did not touch anything that is related to scroll function whatsoever. In the storyboard `Adjust ScrollView Inset` was checked. Once unchecked, it scroll back to field 10 AFTER scrolling to field 1 first. It's weirder.

Comment: You may have written something in delegate methods, provide more insight of your code.

Answer (score 0):

After some days of screaming at my screen for exactly the same problem, I just found the simplest of the simplest solutions that so far completely solves this mentioned issue for me. For the UIScrollView, in the property inspector, set the property 'Key board' to 'Dismiss on drag'. By default it is set to 'Do not dismiss'.

Also possible to do it programmatically:

```
myScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

I wish I could tell you why, that I cannot. But it works for me.